# Why do nested dictionaries update retroactively?

Tags: vba

If you have a normal dictionary key and you set a variable equal to that key's definition and then change the value of that variable, the definition within the dictionary won't change unless you re-save it in the dictionary.  However, as you can see by running the sub below, if you have a nested dictionary and change anything within it, you don't need to resave it in the original dictionary for the changes to take affect.  Anything you add or change will still be reflected in the original dictionary.  The only exception is when you set the dictionary equal to Nothing.  In that case, the nested dictionary will still exist in the original dictionary.  Is there a good explanation for this?

```
Sub dictionarytest()

Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

MsgBox dic2.Count

dic.Add "key", dic2

dic2.Add "a", 1

dic2.Add "b", 1

'Why isn't this necessary?
'dic.item("key") = dic2

Set dic2 = dic.Item("key")

MsgBox dic2.Count

dic2.Add "c", 1

Set dic2 = Nothing

Set dic2 = dic.Item("key")

MsgBox dic2.Count


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're describing is more a difference between object and non-object variables than any idiosyncrasy of the dictionary object itself.

**Object Variables**
As I understand it, when VBA creates an instance of an object, every variable you create and "set" equal to that object doesn't actual equal it but is a reference to that object.  That means that multiple variables (references) can exist for a shared object.  If you set one variable equal to nothing, that does not necessitate that all references be set to nothing. However, if you change one of the object's properties through one reference, you will see this change in all references (and you can think of the items in a dictionary as a sort of property).

**Non-Object Variables**
If you assign a non-object variable to a dictionary, you are not assigning a reference to anything, but creating a new variable within the dictionary that is given the assigned variable's value. Since these variables carry their own values and are not references, after the corresponding dictionary variable is created and given the assigned variable's value, they go their separate ways and retain no connection.

---

Here is a similar example to what you posted that also displays similar behavior with a worksheet object. Note, output is sent to the immediate window using Debug.Print.

```
Sub example()
Dim d1 As Dictionary
Dim d2 As Dictionary

Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

d1.Add 1, d2
d1(1).Add "a", 1
d1(1).Add "b", 2
Debug.Print d2.Count

Set d2 = Nothing
Debug.Print d1(1).Count

d1.Add 2, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set d2 = d1(2)
Debug.Print d2.Count

Set d1(2) = Nothing
Debug.Print d2.Count


Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(1)
d1.Add 3, ws
d1(3).Name = "ABC"
Debug.Print ws.Name
Set ws2 = ws
Debug.Print ws.Name & ws2.Name & d1(3).Name
Set ws = Sheets(2)
Debug.Print ws.Name & ws2.Name & d1(3).Name
End Sub
```