# nested dictionary updating values retroactively

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am running into issues constructing a nested dictionary in python. A similar scenario as described here: [Why do nested dictionaries update retroactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461341/why-do-nested-dictionaries-update-retroactively).

I do not want this retroactive update behaviour, and i was wondering how best to override it. I can get it work properly by using copy.deepcopy(), but this is incredibly slow for large datasets.

Essentially what this code is supposed to do is make a nested dictionary using the first two columns of `fileData` as keys to point to the last two columns.

example:

```
header = ['key1', 'key2', 'value1', 'value2']
fileData = [[1, 1, 67, 89],
            [1, 2, 34, 54],
            [1, 3, 56, 56],
            [2, 1, 89, 89],
            [2, 2, 89, 45],
            [2, 3, 45, 45]]
data = {}
timeData = {}
dictTime = fileData[0][0]
for j in range(len(fileData)):
    record = fileData[j]
    recordData = {}
    for i in range(2, len(record)):
        recordData[header[i]] = record[i]
        timeData[int(record[1])] = recordData
        if j == 2 or j == 5: data[record[0]] = timeData
print(data)
```

Mike

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Please update you question and show the desired output.